# keep getting an error

Tags: java, palindrome

why do i keep getting an error on "int numLength = palNum1.length();?" im trying to finish this lab that im doing for my java class and im stuck on this part. any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Lab6
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
      String pal1, pal2="";
      int palNum1, palNum2, choice;
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("Word(w) or Number(n)?");
      choice = in.nextLine().charAt(0);

      if (choice == 'w') {

          System.out.println("Enter a word: ");
          pal1= in.nextLine();

          int length = pal1.length();


          for ( int i = length - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i-- )
            pal2 = pal2 + pal1.charAt(i);


         if (pal1.equals(pal2))
            System.out.println("The word you entered is a palindrome.");
         else
            System.out.println("The word you entered is not a palindrome.");
        }
      else{

          System.out.println("Enter a bunch of numbers: ");
          palNum1 = in.nextInt();

          int numLength = palNum1.length();


          for ( int j = numLength - 1 ; j >= 0 ; j-- )
            palNum2 = palNum2 + palNum1.charAt(j);

         if (palNum1.equals(palNum2))
            System.out.println("The numbers you entered is a palindrome.");
         else
            System.out.println("The numbers you entered is not a palindrome.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What type is `palNum1`?

Comment: int @SotiriosDelimanolis

Comment: `int` is a primitive type. Do primitive types have methods?

Comment: You need to initialize the value of palNum1. Currently, it is initialized only in else part. It needs to be initialized in if part. If you can't initialize it in if part, then move the declaration too in the else part.

Comment: @vijar `palNum1` doesn't have any methods...

Comment: So what type should i use for palNum1? i want to enter a bunch of numbers as the value for palNum1 so i thought id try int. any suggestions? @SotiriosDelimanolis

Comment: do i still need to declare it in the if part if i only need it in the else part? @vijar

Comment: @programmingnoob from the code, the type of palNum1 is int. You need to change it to String.

Comment: Good practice is to localize your variable as much as possible. If I were you, I would declare it only in else part.

Answer (score 0):

As dasblink said, primitave types don't have methods.
Given what you're trying to do if they enter an integer, you should convert it to a String then basically repeat the code from the first part. Instead of:

```
      System.out.println("Enter a bunch of numbers: ");
      palNum1 = in.nextInt();

      int numLength = palNum1.length();

      for ( int j = numLength - 1 ; j >= 0 ; j-- )
        palNum2 = palNum2 + palNum1.charAt(j);
```

Easy thing to do is convert the int they enter into a String, then repeat code from before:

```
      System.out.println("Enter a bunch of numbers: ");
      palNum1 = in.nextInt();
      // Conver it to String to allow you to easily check if its a palindrome.
      pal1 = Integer.parseInt(palNum1);

      int numLength = pal1.length();

      for ( int j = numLength - 1 ; j >= 0 ; j-- )
        pal2 = pal2 + pal1.charAt(j);
```

palNum2 is never needed.

EDIT:
Sorry if I confused you, I meant that you read in the palindrome as an int(same as you originally did), but then you convert it to a String, then treat it as before.
complete code for the else:

```
  else{
      // If you are here, user is entering an int.
      System.out.println("Enter a bunch of numbers: ");
      palNum1 = in.nextInt();
      pal1 = Integer.parseInt(palNum1);

      int numLength = pal1.length();

      for ( int j = numLength - 1 ; j >= 0 ; j-- )
        pal2 = pal2 + pal1.charAt(j);

     if (pa1.equals(pal2))
        System.out.println("The numbers you entered is a palindrome.");
     else
        System.out.println("The numbers you entered is not a palindrome.");
    }
```

Comment: ur totally right but now its not outputing whether it is a palindrome or not.

Comment: Did you change the code in the if statement after my amended code so that it used pal1, pal2 instead of palNum1, palNum2

Comment: yes i did now its giving me an error on pal1 = in.nextInt(); @Will_61